# Return string from query Doctrine

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have a query that sums up the total of fields in my database.

```
//HoursRepository.php

public function findHoursTotal($user)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('h')
        ->where('h.user = :user')
        ->select('SUM(h.total)')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

This query returns:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    1 => "52400"
  ]
]
```

My question is how do i get just the "52400" result as a string and not in an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `getSingleScalarResult()`, bellow the usage example :

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('h')
        ->where('h.user = :user')
        ->select('SUM(h.total)')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
```